# Which database should I use for offline Flutter Desktop App?

Tags: database, flutter, flutter-desktop

I am working on a simple flutter desktop application to practice flutter desktop. The problem is on my mind is the database selection. I think about MySQL but I do not want to force users to install MySQL. I want a database to operate locally, offline, device-based and not needed to install anything extra like sqlite for mobile (I do not know is sqlite available on desktop). I want it to be like get the .exe and run the app like c#. So, another question is does flutter need to be installed to run flutter desktop apps? Can you enlighten me a bit about flutter desktop if you have experience?

Comment: Check out https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite_common_ffi

Answer (score 1):

Database to use:

- I'll recommend Hive db to use. It is no-sql and fast database. Does not require any additional software installation on desktop.
  With hive db same code will work on desktop, web and mobile apps.

To run your flutter projet exe on Windows desktop, you don't need flutter to be installed on that desktop.